# LiveUSB 15.10 never stops loading

Tags: dual-boot, windows, live-usb, 15.10, windows-10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10 and following [this guide](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html), but when I choose the "Try Ubuntu" option after rebooting, it goes into that purple "loading screen" with the little dots that turn white and orange as it loads, and never leaves. I waited for something to happen for about 3h and nothing did. There is no error message, it just never stops loading.

What could it be?

--EDIT:

So I did as suggested and pressed ESC when ubuntu was loading. The last two lines are:

```
[   ***] A start job is running for Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling (22s / no limit) [59.252349] ------------[ cut here ]------------

[   59.253507] WARNING: CPU: 4 PID: 0 at /build/linux-AxjFAn/linux-4.2.0/kernel/watchdog.c:311 watchdog_overflow_callback+0x79/0xa0()
```

A similar message appears a little bit before that, but with CPU: 7 PID: 1120 instead.

If there is some way to copy the entire log and paste it here so it can help, I'd love to hear it; right now, I'm reproducing it by typing.

--EDIT:

Deactivated secure boot, used Rufus this time for the USB Stick, what I get is the following:

[image]

Choosing the option "Install Ubuntu" as opposed to "Try Ubuntu" runs and gives me something else, which I'll post in a comment because I don't have enough rep.

This "Call Trace" thing appears many times, with stuff under it whose meaning I do not know.

[image]

Comment: Try hitting escape when you're on the purple screen

Comment: Just hitting it once or keeping it pressed?

Comment: just a single hit should do it. You should see diagnostic information about the boot in real-time, then you can see where it has a problem. Or it might just work this time.

Comment: Did as asked, editted the original post to include the extra information.

Comment: Aforementioned third link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f8GpDE5ZDqplzaEzPlqmMnizvDaOBjAw-w/view?usp=sharing